# create-react-app in VS Code throwing unauthorized access on Windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, windows-10, create-react-app

When I try to create react app on my Windows machine, I keep getting unauthorized access. I haven't experienced this behaviour on Mac, so I don't really know what might causing the issue.

In the VS Code's Terminal I ran following commands:

```
PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox> npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\Foo_Bar\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Foo_Bar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
added 91 packages from 45 contributors in 6.923s

PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox> create-react-app --version 
create-react-app : File C:\Users\Foo_Bar\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 ca 
nnot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
 about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ create-react-app --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox> create-react-app test-app
create-react-app : File C:\Users\Foo_Bar\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 ca
nnot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
 about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

+ create-react-app test-app
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox>
```

It looks like `npm install -g create-react-app` was successful. Creating the actual app or checking version failed, though. Does anyone have any idea what might be the reason of that?

EDIT:
`Node` and `npm` versions are following:

```
PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox> node --version
v12.13.0
PS C:\Users\Foo_Bar\sandbox> npm --version
6.12.0
```

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: I did. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using

```
npx create-react-app **foldername**
```

i had same problem and it was the faster and easier solution

Comment: npx v6.14.5 gets halt for infinite times on windows 10. node v14.3.0 and npm v6.14.5.